# problem identifying linearly independent vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

I am a complete newbie in vectors, I am self-studying the below section of a book:

[identifying linearly independent vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5sEp.png)

It might be too simple, but. I do not understand how the author arrives to the conclusion that "the unique solution" is c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0.

Wouldn't

- c_1=2
- c_2= -1
- c_3= -1

be three constants that make c_1+c_2+c_3=0 ?

After the "implies that" I do understand the first line, but then the other two I do not... Is the author just testing random values? (even more strange to me is why the author left a blank space between 2*c_1 [space?!]- 2*c_3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix},
\mathbf x_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf x_3 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}
$

$c_1\mathbf x_1 + c_2\mathbf x_2 +c_3\mathbf x_3 = \mathbf 0$

If this is true, then the sum of the first elements equals 0, the sum of the second elements equals 0, and the sum of the 3rd elements equals 0.

or

$\mathbf c_1 \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix} +
\mathbf c_2  \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix} + 
\mathbf c_3  \begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}c_1+c_2+c_3\\2c_1 - 2c_3 \\c_1-c_2+c_3\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Now solve the system of equations to show there is only one solution and it is $c_1 = c_2=c_3 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: Wouldn't

c_1=2

c_2= -1

c_3= -1

be three constants that make c_1+c_2+c_3=0 ?

You are correct. But there are two more equations that need to be satisfied: 
$$2c_1 - 2c_3 = 0$$ and
$$ c_1-c_2+c_3 = 0$$

and your numbers
c_1=2
c_2= -1
c_3= -1
don't satisfy those.